# Why can't I use cartopy to plot certain time averages of the same dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I have a 3-dimensional xarray DataArray of changes in surface temperature with coordinates of time, lat and lon. I am visualizing the data using Cartopy. You can find the 125 MB file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1edgPoJuEdI-Tnyk8VUv0ZOUyP1CrFWJB/view?usp=sharing).

While producing plots of time-averages over different periods, I've found that I'm unable to produce orthographic projections when including certain time steps, such as the 132nd (index 131) time. Here is a plot of the time average from 0 to 130:

[image: correct spatial map of temperature changes]

But this happens when I instead perform the time average from 0 to 131:

[image: incorrect spatial map of temperature changes]

Here is the code I used to produce the plots:

```
# import statements

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = "jpg"

# read in data
ens_mean = xr.open_dataarray('temp_changes_ens_mean.nc')

# time average subset of data
to_plot = ens_mean.isel(time=slice(None,131)).mean(dim='time') # change 130 to 131 to break cartopy

# add cyclic point to avoid white lines
data = to_plot
lon = to_plot.coords['lon']

lon_idx = data.dims.index('lon')
wrap_data, wrap_lon = add_cyclic_point(data.values, coord=lon, axis=lon_idx)


# make an orthographic plot centered on north pole

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,3.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(0, 90))

ax.coastlines()

im = ax.contourf(wrap_lon, to_plot.lat, wrap_data,
                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# add colorbar
cb = fig.colorbar(im,orientation='horizontal',shrink=0.5,pad=0.05)

cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
cb.set_label('ΔSAT (K)',fontsize=8)

plt.tight_layout(w_pad=0.05)
plt.show()
```

This occurs whether I add a cyclic point or not. I am able to make quick plots of the data using matplotlib or xarray's built-in plotting without error. I've already checked for NaN values in the data. Lastly, if I remove the transform argument in the contourf line, it is able to produce a coherent plot, which leads me to think it is the transformation step that produces this odd plot.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Something goes wrong with the coordinates! The green area is just zoom to the north pole compared to the case, where the script works. At least the case seems to be like this to me.

Comment: @msi_gerva I think you're right, based on the automatically generated colorbar. Any ideas on how to reset the coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_global()` method to reset the coordinate limits:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# --------------------------------------------
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#%matplotlib inline
#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = "jpg"

# read in data
ens_mean = xr.open_dataarray('temp_changes_ens_mean.nc')

# time average subset of data
to_plot = ens_mean.isel(time=slice(None,131)).mean(dim='time') # change 130 to 131 to break cartopy

# add cyclic point to avoid white lines
data = to_plot
lon = to_plot.coords['lon']

lon_idx = data.dims.index('lon')
wrap_data, wrap_lon = add_cyclic_point(data.values, coord=lon, axis=lon_idx)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# this is not working:
xlims = (np.min(ens_mean['lon']),np.max(ens_mean['lon'])); 
ylims = (np.min(ens_mean['lat']),np.max(ens_mean['lat']));
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
lon = to_plot.coords['lon']
# ====================================================================================
# make an orthographic plot centered on north pole
# Let us make a working/satisfying plot:

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,3.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(0, 90))

ax.coastlines()

im = ax.contourf(wrap_lon, to_plot.lat, wrap_data,
                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# add colorbar
cb = fig.colorbar(im,orientation='horizontal',shrink=0.5,pad=0.05)

cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
cb.set_label('ΔSAT (K)',fontsize=8)

plt.tight_layout(w_pad=0.05)

ax.set_global();
#ax.set_xlim(xlims);
#ax.set_ylim(ylims);

plt.show()
```

Comment: Super simple fix. Thanks for this. I did notice that when I messed around with the colormap separately, this also seemed to fix the issue. There's something going on behind the scenes, but it's beyond me! Take care :)